# Free alternative for Gentle Mouse software?

Tags: software-rec, mouse-click

I've been trying out some software on Windows XP called [Gentle Mouse](http://www.gentlemouse.com/); its function is to reduce mouse clicks. After the cursor stops moving, a menu pops up and lets the user choose different actions such as left-click/right-click/double-click. The user can then just move the cursor to the corresponding box and the action will be immediately performed.

[image: Screenshot]

This application greatly reduces my finger strain caused by mouse clicks. Unfortunately it is not free, so I really want to see if a freeware alternative exists.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please post your OS, Not exactly what you need but is free and will reduce some repetitive clicks, good software is worth every penny, consider buying GM...http://majorgeeks.com/PTFB_Push_the_Freakin_Button_d4416.html

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot out there but my grand-dad uses [this](http://www.polital.com/pnc/)

> Point-N-Click is a FREE stand-alone on-screen virtual mouse designed
>   for anyone with a disability that makes it difficult or impossible to
>   click a physical computer mouse. As long as they can move a mouse,
>   trackball or other pointing device, they can send mouse clicks to
>   virtually any Windows application or DOS application that can run
>   within a window and even many that are full screen.

Answer (score 1):

Not really the same type of thing, but it is possible to direct the mouse without a mouse at all using the speech recognition software in MS Windows 7. Not sure about the OS you have, or if this will work but you, but for more info see [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/Windows7/Use-the-computer-without-the-mouse-or-keyboard-alternative-input-devices).

Answer (score 0):

I tried the Point-n-Click free software, but it is much to tedious and slow to use in a professional environment.  I have arthritis in my hands and work in the IT industry so it's imperative to have a responsive alternative to mouse clicking.  My index finger has developed a painful and large arthritic node from all the mouse clicking, so Gentlemouse is perfect for my purposes.
It is a bit expensive at £40 or so, but I will try to get the company to subsidise the purchase.
Note: Set the executable properties (compatiblity) to "Run as Administrator".  This will ensure that the software operates across all software products on your computer.
BIG NOTE for IT industry users: Installed on your local PC, it will also work on any VM Ware you run over remote desktop.